# How to link to a CDN in a folder for multiple pages in HTML

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I spent quite a while Googling this, but I just don't know how to formulate the question because I likely don't know the correct words to help me find the answer.

I am wanting to test out Bootstrap 5 on a website with multiple pages to just mess around with it. What I am trying to do is have the CDN in a folder and then link to the CDN for each page in the  tags. That way, when they update the alpha, I can just update the link in one spot and have it go to each page instead of needing to go to each page one-by-one and update the link there. Does that make sense? Is this possible?

Edit: To help with understanding what I am using here. I am working with GitHub Pages which doesn't allow for PHP.

Comment: GitHub pages is powered by Jekyll, so you could use their layouts feature as well: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/layouts/. That way any changes to the CSS URL would be replicated on all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single `css` file for your project and named it whatever you want for example `bootstrap.css`. Then you can import that `bootstrap-5-aplha` link in that `css` and use that `css` file in anypage you want to. So that whenver you want to change you just need to change that `link` of your import.

```
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

And if you want to do the same for your js file, you just need to create a single `js` file and named it whatever you want for examples `bootstrap.js` and call it with `script` tag just above the closing `</body>` tag `html` and then in your `js` file you have to paste this code:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
var script2 = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script2.type = 'text/javascript';

script.src = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"; 
script2.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js';

script.integrity="sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/";
script2.integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo";

script.crossOrigin="anonymous";
script2.crossOrigin="anonymous";

document.body.appendChild(script2);  
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

It is generating two `script` files for your project one is `bootstrap.min.js` and the other one is `popper.js`

I am calling `script2` before the `script` tag because popper have to be called before `bootstrap.min.js`.

whenever you want to update the js link you just need to update `src` of both.

Don't forget to update your question also as it is highlighting only the css part.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but how do I do this for JavaScript? I thought it would have been the same process, but I am learning that it is not. There are so many ways that I have seen to import JS, but I'm not sure which one to use for this scenario.

Comment: I have updated my answer do check the updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. What you need to do is create a file, let's call it *header.** * with the ** extension to be dependent on your stack. Finally, you need to connect this file with your core code. You need to be aware of course about the path when you connect the files and depending on the languages you use the syntax will be different. Is it just an `html` page with `bootstrap`? Then the easiest way I guess is to link them with PHP, or at least that's what I have done so far with projects.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply! I just edited my question to include that I am trying to use GitHub Pages which doesn't allow PHP. I had thought about PHP, but since they don't allow it, I was at a loss of what to do. Sorry that I didn't include that in the original question.

Comment: So is it just html and css?

Comment: With some JS. Fareed helped me with the @import url. I really appreciate how quickly you jumped in to help out. I think PHP would have worked if I weren't using GitHub which blocks it. Thanks, again!